# VBA issue, Private Function error when trying to get my macro to work

Tags: excel, vba

When pressing the macro, it comes up with a Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. I finally got it to slightly work for 64bit, but now am running into this issue.

```
Private Function getUser() As String
    Dim strUser As String

    'Create a buffer
    strUser = String(100, Chr(0))
    'Get the username
    getUser strUser, 100
    'strip the rest of the buffer
    strUser = Left(strUser, InStr(strUser, Chr(0)) - 1)
    getUser = strUser
End Function
```

Here's the other one with getUser in it.

```
On Error Resume Next

Set MyOL = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If MyOL Is Nothing Then
    Set MyOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
strUser = getUser
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Documents and Settings\" & strUser & "\Local Settings\Temp\" & " " & staffname & " - OT Survey for " & ActiveSheet.name & ".xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: What are you try to do?

Comment: What is `getUser strUser, 100` supposed to mean inside of the definition of a function called `getUser`? Do you have a sub of the same name? If so, that really doesn't make sense.

Comment: In Excel VBA, I've never seen the C-like idiom of creating a string buffer and reading into it data character by character (from where, exactly?). VBA does have a little-used `Get` statement, but that function requires a file handle. This function is obscure.

Comment: So we have an overtime sheet that when filled out and the send macro is clicked it would auto send an email to a senior manager in our office. However, since we got new computers it hasn't been working properly at all. This was actually made by another individual before me, so I don't know what the getUser strUser, 100 is supposed to mean.

Comment: It seems that there was a function or sub of 2 variables called `GetUser`, which doesn't make sense inside the definition of a function with the same name which takes no arguments. The fact that this is a compile error has nothing at all to do with 32 vs. 64 bits and whether or not your computers are new.

Comment: My apologies, I'm very new at this and just trying to get this to work instead of having to make a new sheet. Is there anything I should try to delete?

Comment: Somewhere in the project you should probably be able to find a sub or function called `GetUser` which this other individual wrote.

Comment: I edited my post to include the other function

Answer (score 2):

Your code is caused by `getUser strUser, 100`.
It's recursively calling itself (i.e. it's within the function called `getuser`), and is trying to pass two arguments to the function while the function header doesn't ask for them `Private Function getUser() As String`.
Basically everything that @JohnColeman commented.

How to fix that I've no idea.

The code does resemble what I've posted below, which returns the system user name.
Put the first line at the top of the module and remove `PtrSafe` if not on 64 bit.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function api_GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Public Function getUser() As String
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim NBuffer As String
    Dim Buffsize As Long
    Dim Wok As Long

    Buffsize = 256
    NBuffer = Space$(Buffsize)

    Wok = api_GetUserName(NBuffer, Buffsize)
    getUser = Trim$(NBuffer)

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Saying all that - your `SaveAs`,where you use the user name, is looking for the temp folder - would just `ENVIRON("Temp")` work there?

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Environ("Temp") & "\ " & staffname & " - OT Survey for " & ActiveSheet.Name & ".xlsm"
```

Comment: "How to fix that I've no idea" :) -- you've given a good answer to a seemingly unanswerable question.

Comment: So what I did to semi resolve the issue was remove the getUser strUser, 100 line and the submission button works now! However, the excel sheet it's supposed to save doesn't save any of the information entered and everyone kept sending it in blank even though they had spent time to fill it out. I wonder what could be causing that now... Thank you for all your help so far everyone!